# Custom subdomain name for blob CDN endpoint causes error 400

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, domain-name, azure-cdn

I'm trying to set up a custom domain name for a blob CDN endpoint, following [these](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain/) instructions, but can't seem to access my content using the subdomain static.mydomain.com. I've created the following record with my registrar:

```
Subdomain: static

Type: CNAME

TTL: 7200

Data: blobconatinername.blob.core.windows.net.
```

For example, I can access this file (note https): 
https://blobcontanername.blob.core.windows.net/somefile.mp3

But trying to access this file

http://static.mydomain.com/somefile.mp3

I get an invalid URI error (an error 400):

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>InvalidUri</Code>
<Message>
The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server. RequestId:c5ec4859-0001-0079-0bf8-961dfa000000 Time:2016-04-15T09:22:32.1317877Z
</Message>
<UriPath>
http://static.mydomain.com/somefile.mp3
</UriPath>
</Error>
```

Resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you access the file via the CDN endpoint, `yourcdnendpoint.azureedge.net/path/to/file`?

Shouldn't `static.yourdomain.com` point to the CDN endpoint, not your blob storage?

```
Subdomain: static

Type: CNAME

TTL: 7200

Data: yourcdnendpoint.azureedge.net.
```

Also, the domain you are using must be verified. The process is described at https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/documentation/articles/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain/

Comment: Yes, it's accessible via http://mycdnendpoint.azureedge.net/somefile.mp3! I'll try adjusting the CNAME record as you wrote and see if it helps. I am confused about the difference between a blob storage and CDN endpoint I guess.

Comment: The CNAME record has propagated (https://www.digwebinterface.com/ output below) but I still get a 400 error when going to http://static.mydomain.com/somefile.mp3. `static.mydomain.com@8.8.4.4 (Default):
static.mydomain.com. 7199 IN CNAME mycdnendpoint.azureedge.net.
mycdnendpoint.azureedge.net. 1799 IN CNAME mycdnendpoint.ec.azureedge.net.
mycdnendpoint.ec.azureedge.net. 3599 IN CNAME ---.wpc.v0cdn.net.
---.wpc.v0cdn.net. 3599 IN A xx.xx.xx.xxx
`

Comment: Have you verified your domain using a `cdnverify` entry? This is explained here: https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/documentation/articles/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain/

Comment: Yes I did it some days ago with this entry: 
`Subdomain: cdnverify.static
Type: CNAME
TTL: 7200 
Data: cdnverify.mycdnendpoint.azureedge.net.`

I've done step 8 and 9 in the instructions (Register a custom domain for an Azure CDN endpoint using the intermediary cdnverify subdomain). (Incidentally, logging into the old Azure portal reveals no CDN nor storage services!?)

Comment: CDN and storages are different between the new/old portals. They are referred to as "Classic". Where do you end up if you do a `dig` on static.mydomain.com now? Still as before?
A 404 indicates that the file is not found, could it be a problem with your path?

Comment: Today it works! Maybe it was a matter of time. I can finally access my file with static.mydomain.com/path/to/file.mp3. (`dig` on static.mydomain.com results in the same as before.) Thanks for your help! Hallelujah. Eureka. Viola!

Answer (score 2):

This 400 error occurred for us too - the fix was to assign the **Origin Host Header** value. We are using the **Verizon Premium CDN** plan in Azure - MS support advised us that **Host Header** is required despite it appearing as optional in the *Azure Portal UI*.

#### CDN Profile => CDN Endpoint => Origin => Origin Host Header

[image]